# How can I vary the number of arguments/vectors in polym? Using do.call() in lm() call is causing problems

Tags: r, regression

I am using polym, and I can't figure out how to vary the number of vectors used in a polynomial regression. The number should depend on how many features, f, are in the training dataframe. Right now I'm stuck doing something like this:

```
if (f==1) {
   model <- lm(Price ~ polym(X1,degree=3, raw=T), data=train)
} else if (f==2) {
   model <- lm(Price ~ polym(X1,X2,degree=3, raw=T), data=train)
} else if (f==3) {
   model <- lm(Price ~ polym(X1,X2,X3,degree=3, raw=T), data=train)
} else if (f==4) {
   model <- lm(Price ~ polym(X1,X2,X3,X4,degree=3, raw=T), data=train)
} else if (f==5) {
   model <- lm(Price ~ polym(X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,degree=3, raw=T), data=train)
}
```

My initial approach was to use do.call() as follows:

```
features <- as.list(train[,1:f])
degree<-3
polym_args <- c(features, degree=degree, raw=T)
model <- lm(train$Price ~ do.call(polym,polym_args))
summary(model)
predict(model, newdata=test)
```

This works when fitting the model and viewing the summary information, but caused a peculiar problem when predicting new problems. Calling predict() on new data returns the original fitted data points from training data instead of new predictions, along with the following error:

```
Warning message:
'newdata' had 4 rows but variables found have 100 rows
```

(I verified that this was a problem with do.call() by  removing it and trying a normal polym specification, which did not cause the error above.)

Is there a straightforward way to use all of the available vectors with polym?

Example train data:

```
X1  X2  Price
0.31    0.76    1312.07
0.99    0.23    717.1
0.84    0.29    607.91
0.28    0.45    270.4
0.07    0.83    289.88
0.66    0.8 830.85
0.73    0.92    1038.09
0.57    0.43    455.19
0.43    0.89    640.17
```

Example test data:

```
X1  X2
0.05    0.54
0.91    0.91
0.31    0.76
0.51    0.31
```

Comment: would you update with a minimal example dataset to reproduce your error?

Comment: @NateDay added, thanks